# What are the roles of <param> tags within the <node> tags in launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I wanna know what the roles of  tags within the  tags are. Let's take a common example:

```
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher"> 
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0"/> 
  </node>
```

Please explain to me. Any answer is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286992/what-are-the-roles-of-%3Cparam%3E-tags-within-the-%3Cnode%3E-tags-in-launch-file?/) by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-29**:
Have you checked the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) ?

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-29**:
Yes, I did check the wiki. But I still can't comprehend the concepts of the naming rules about parameters in ros, so that I am disable to understand what the `<param>` tags within the `<node>` tags mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [this](http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/ROS%20Parameter%20Server.html) would help you understand what's behind the `param` tag.

To use your example with the `robot_state_publisher` node you can use the param tag because [here](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/blob/kinetic-devel/src/joint_state_listener.cpp#L58) line 58 you define a variable that can be set whitin the launch file using the `param` tag and if you don't define it you still have a default value. And you can see that there are two others parameters than can be set so this is possible too :

```
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />
    <param name="use_tf_static" type="bool" value="false" />
    <param name="ignore_timestamp" type="bool" value="true" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
Thank you so much for your answer, so the `<param>` tags within `<node>` tags are like the formal parameters of a function in programming language, am I correct?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:
You can say that but it's more like if you values in differents nodes you need to adapt for your application, instead of changing the source code of each node you will change those parameters in your launch file. It allows you to see all your parameters used for each node in the same file.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:
But be aware that you have to define this in the source code, with the same example if there wasn't this line in the code :

```
n_tilde.param("publish_frequency", publish_freq, 50.0);
```

You wouldn't be able to use `<param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="30.0" />`

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:
Additionnaly there is an `<arg>` tag within the `launch` tag allowing you to pass arguments in command when executing a roslaunch.
For example you might have seen this :

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:='$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
```

The model part is an argument.

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
Thank you for your guidance.

```
<node name="urdf_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-urdf -model cambot -param robot_description"/>
```

I also like to know what this `args` attribute stands for.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:
You should always check the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) (the tag reference part) it's all detailled for each tag.
The `args` is the same thing as my previous comment but instead of typing it in the terminal you define the arguments directly in the launch file.

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
I've read the [page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) you provided, but it does not seem to solve my question. It just gives an example of `<node name="add_two_ints_client" pkg="beginner_tutorials" type="add_two_ints_client" args="$(arg a) $(arg b)" />`, but without explanation.

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
Then I try to read this [page](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node), it simply gives a statement of args attribute() without further explanation.
Here is the explanation of this page about args:

```
args="arg1 arg2 arg3"(optional)

Pass arguments to node.
```

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:
Here's an exemple with urdf_tutorial, in my previous comment I said you can use :

`roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:='$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'`

There is an argument defined in command, if you check the display.launch you will see :

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:

So the command is actually :

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch -d $(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf.rviz" model:='$(find urdf_tutorial)/urdf/01-myfirst.urdf'
```

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
Does this mean that the contents(`-d $(arg rvizconfig)`) of `args` attribute will be added to the command line(`rosrun rviz rviz`) when the roslaunch command starts the `node` that contains this `args` attribute?

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
Now I kinda understand it. Thank you very much for your careful guidance,sir.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-03-30**:
It won't be executed like a rosrun command but if you do it manually yes you would have to write the rosrun like you said. And i realized the command in my previous comment is wrong and should have been the one you said.

You're welcome.

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
I know that there is no rosrun, so it's like materialization. Thank you so much!